# VSTS Multiple Private NuGet Feeds

Tags: c#, nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I am planning on transitioning a large DLL project that is used on one large site to multiple small sites that mostly just have the parts from the DLL that they need.  It looked like VSTS would work for that, since I already have a MSDN license and can use package management.

In VSTS, if I wanted to have a feed for the core classes and other feeds for more specific groups of classes, which depend on the core, would all the parts need to be their own VSTS projects?  Is there a way to setup multiple private NuGet feeds with a single VSTS project that is a solution that contains multiple projects, which each build to their own feed?

Comment: Can you use multiple NuGet pack task to generate packages for each project separartely, and use NuGet push tasks to publish different packages into different feeds?

Comment: I don't think I can...  It doesn't seem like I can build the code in the VSTS Project once I try to split it off, since that would need to reference the other part (via NuGet), which doesn't build.